# How to find the value of column name and row name when a value at the intersection is matching a condition

Tags: excel

How to find the value of column name and row name when a value at the intersection is matching a condition

I have this data

```
    TC1 TC2 TC3
TC1 100 87 95    
TC2 88 100 99
```

I need to return the combinations where value is greater then 95 like:

```
TC1,TC1 TC1,TC3 TC2,TC2 TC2,TC3 and so on.
```

Can anyone help here?

Comment: what version of excel?

Answer (score 1):

This is for Excel 2016.

So, you've got your data:

[image]

Highlight it, and then click 'Format as Table' from the Styles Group in the Home ribbon.  (yes, your table has headers)

[image]

With this table in focus, navigate to the 'Data' ribbon, and click 'From Table/Range' in the 'Get & Transform Data' group.  This will open the query editor.  If you're not used to it, don't worry.  Although it can get quite complex in here, we're going to be pretty straightforward.

[image]

Highlight columns TC1, TC2, TC3 (Hold down [control] and click each column header).  Go to the Transform ribbon, and click on 'Unpivot Columns' in the 'Any Column' group.  Look at what happens, it's awesome.

[image]

Now, click the arrow next to the Value column.  Go to 'Number filters' on the drop down.  Pick, 'greater than equal to.'  A 'Filter Rows' dialog opens.  next to 'is greater than or equal to' put in 95.

[image]

Click OK.  Your data set is filtered.  Yes!  Go back to the home tab, click 'Close & Load'

[image]

Admire your gorgeous list of tuples for values greater than 95.

Good luck!  Hope it helps.